# How to make a method of sorting by tags from Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, sorting, firebase-realtime-database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fS504.png)I have never encountered Firebase sorting in flutter, so I have a question. I have a listview of categories, when I click on which I have to show cards with a certain tag, for example, I click on a burger and it shows me all the cards with the tag "burger"[image]
I will be grateful for every answer

I didn't even know where to start, because nothing comes to mind at all, i will be grateful for every answer

Comment: Hi, this is not sorting, it filtering, right ?

Comment: exactly, filtering

Comment: yes, and I gave you a solution answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I'm going to follow the steps for you, we have a collection named **stocks** :

```
final CollectionReference stocks = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('stocks')
```

you want to filter the documents of this collection for each tag, meaning for each tag in your application, you want to show where that tag is inside the document's **tags**
so before you call the `get()` filter them with what you want :

```
final pizzaDocumentsQuery = stocks.where("tags", arrayContains: "pizza");
```

this will filter them based on what documents have the **pizza** tag in the **tags** list

then, you can call `get()` to load them from the firestore database :

```
QuerySnapshot pizzaDocuments = await pizzaDocumentsQuery.get();
```

that's it, you have it.

Hope this helps you.